# XSLT 1.0 - returning repeating child nodes in XSL

Tags: recursion, xslt-1.0

I have some XML that is produced by system but the order of the XML is not always consistent, a delete make the fields listed out put in a different order from and update. In the XML the fields in the upper entity <SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS> and <MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS> are being delivered in the opposite way round for the the delete and update.

The system receiving the XML needs the XML to be consistently ordered. It is desired to fix the XML via an XSL  before posting out rather than altering the XSD in the receiving system.

I therefore need to impose and XML over the XSL to make it always be ordered correctly.

I'm currently stuck with what I think is a recursion issue but I can't figure out the syntax. I tried also to look at the Muenchian method but am failing to see how I would include that but keep the desired structure. I tried using a multiple templates method and selecting by node and couldn't make it work although I suspect this might be the way to resolve it. (TBH I have gone round in a big circle and I don't really know anymore!). I feel like I used to know how to do this which is even more frustrating!

A stripped down version of the XML:

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ST2-SMO-CX>
 <SMO>
  <SMO.CAMS>
   <MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS>TT1003</MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
   <SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS>220061574/1</SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
      <MAV>
    <MAV.CAMS>
     <MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS>TT1003</MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
     <AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS>2022/3</AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
     <MAB>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>001</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>002</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>003</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
     </MAB>
     <MAVT>
      <MAVT.CAMS>
       <MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS>1</MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS>
      </MAVT.CAMS>
     </MAVT>
    </MAV.CAMS>
   </MAV>
  </SMO.CAMS>
 </SMO>
</ST2-SMO-CX>
```

...
The basic XSL that delivers the structure but does not repeat the <MAB.CAMS> nodes.
...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/xml"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
<xsl:for-each select="/ST2-SMO-CX/SMO/SMO.CAMS">
<ST2-SMO-CX>
<SMO>
<SMO.CAMS>
<SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS"/></SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS"/></MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
  <MAV>
   <MAV.CAMS>
    <MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="//MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS"/></MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
    <AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="//AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS"/></AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
    <MAB>
     <MAB.CAMS>
      <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="//./MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS"/></MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
      <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="//./MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS"/></MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
     </MAB.CAMS>
    </MAB>
    <MAVT>
     <MAVT.CAMS>
             <MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS><xsl:value-of select="//./MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS"/></MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS>
     </MAVT.CAMS>
    </MAVT>
   </MAV.CAMS>
  </MAV>
</SMO.CAMS>
</SMO>
</ST2-SMO-CX>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...

The desired Output is to be able to replicate the XML from the input. The number of Child <MAB.CAMS> nodes is variable, can be one and up but never zero.

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ST2-SMO-CX>
 <SMO>
  <SMO.CAMS>
   <SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS>220061574/1</SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
   <MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS>TT1003</MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS>
      <MAV>
    <MAV.CAMS>
     <MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS>TT1003</MOD_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
     <AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS>2022/3</AYR_CODE.MAV.CAMS>
     <MAB>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>001</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>002</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
      <MAB.CAMS>
       <MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>TT1003-02</MAP_CODE.MAB.CAMS>
       <MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>003</MAB_SEQ.MAB.CAMS>
      </MAB.CAMS>
     </MAB>
     <MAVT>
      <MAVT.CAMS>
       <MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS>1</MAV_NPER.MAVT.CAMS>
      </MAVT.CAMS>
     </MAVT>
    </MAV.CAMS>
   </MAV>
  </SMO.CAMS>
 </SMO>
</ST2-SMO-CX>
```

...

Comment: So what exactly needs to be changed in the input?

Comment: Very little to be honest , its just being reprocessed so that we can control the order of fields. The XSL that I have done only lists the first <MAB.CAMS> node so if it listed all nodes then it would be complete.

Comment: Very little is not nothing. If you need the output to be identical to the input, then there is no need for any transformation. I don't see that your attempt changes any "order of fields". So what exactly is your purpose here?

Comment: P.S. If you want a transformation that replicates the input, you can use a stylesheet with only the [identity transform template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT). But it accomplishes nothing except wasting CPU power and electricity.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the XML original output with the upper entity elements transposed and then added the desired output to show it corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I am also confused by your question. The one thing that I am convinced of is that you are approaching this incorrectly.

If you wanted to change the order in which `SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS` and `MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS` appear in the output, and leave everything else as it is, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SMO.CAMS"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SPR_CODE.SMO.CAMS"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MAV"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This approach leaves room for additional templates in case you need to perform other changes.

Comment: That's perfect! I tried to use the 
...<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>... but made such an incomprehensible mess I couldn't make it work. Thank you

Comment: If I needed to transform the value MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS that is covered by <xsl:apply-templates select="MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS"/>, is it best to try and use another template and then use xsl:call-template to effect the transformation?
I had a try incorporating '''<xsl:call-template name="Template1">
<xsl:with-param name="SMO_MCRD.SMO.CAMS" select="concat(0, $node1value)"/>
</xsl:call-template>''' to try and replace Nulls with a 0 but couldn't get the syntax correct

Comment: To apply a further transformation to the MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS  element, you need to add a template that **matches** MOD_CODE.SMO.CAMS. This template will be selected and applied as the result of the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction. There should be no need to **call** any template.